# How to create droplet with digital ocean api v2?

Tags: php, digital-ocean

I want to create droplet but I am getting error in `curl_close()`. How can I create droplet ? It is giving me error like:

```
 Warning: curl_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
$data = 'name=TestDroplet&region=ams3&size=512mb&image=449676322';
$create_droplet = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array(
    $create_droplet, 
    array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "METESTING",
        CURLOPT_POST => 0,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: Bearer 0503e2f686f11fb5b7f81c8baf6434b63103715422cb719711f77dde44d768a4',
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
    )
);

$create = curl_exec($create_droplet);
curl_close($create);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($create);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: If you want the close to be successful, try `curl_close($create_droplet)`, which is the resource that came back from the init command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to [`curl_close`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-close.php) the result of the [`curl_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) which is FALSE on failure, or TRUE. In your case since you used `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, it's the result of your execution.

```
$create = curl_exec($create_droplet);
curl_close($create_droplet);
```

Relevant PHP [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php):

> **Description**
>
> `curl_exec ( CurlHandle $handle ) : string|bool`
>
> Execute the given cURL session.
>
> This function should be called after initializing a cURL session and all the options for the session are set.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `handle` - A cURL handle returned by [curl_init()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php).
>
> **Return Values**
>
> Returns **true** on success or **false** on failure. However, if the **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER** option is [set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), it will return the result on success, **false** on failure.

Comment: How can i print that data ? Can you please write code for that ? I am new in this api so.

Comment: @Nikul, it's in your `$create` variable. Try inspecting its contents.

Comment: I need code so i can better understand. Can you please update my code and place it here ?

Comment: @Nikul: we generally discourage "please write my code for me" requests. People are willing to help, but not work for free. Please try it yourself, as suggested.

Comment: Thanks #amphetamachine